# How to find string in tableview and update array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

i am loading tableviewcell with textfield. i am loading one array in tableview. and i have one more option called editing the textfields and changing names also. if enter same name name what it is already existed in array. that time i am showing alert but if revert back to original name i don't want to show alert

```
NSMutableArray *brokenCars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"Audi A6", @"BMW Z3",
                              @"Audi Quattro", @"Audi TT", nil];

if (isEditMode)
        {
            if ([tempstr length]>0)
            {
                for (Playerinfo *player in brokenCars)
                {
                    if ([player.playername isEqualToString:tempstr])
                    {

                        isPlayerExist = YES;
                        if (occurrences>1)
                        {
                        CustomAlert *alert = [[CustomAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please choose a different name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitle:@""];
                        [alert showInView:self.view];
                        NSIndexPath *indexPath1=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow inSection:0];
                        [_playerTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1 animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem boosa please tell ur problem exactly i could not understand your question

Comment: do u want the code for search bar methods